# Jetpack Compose does not compile in a multi-module project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having an issue trying to add jetpack compose in a multi-module project
I'm using Android Studio 4.2 Canary 3

the gradle task that fails is :module:compileDebugKotlin with this error message

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
```

my :module build.gradle looks like this

```
android {

    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {

        jvmTarget = "1.8"

        // Compose compiler based on 1.4 but set 1.3 for compatibility
        apiVersion = "1.3"
    }

    buildFeatures {

        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {

        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.3.70-dev-withExperimentalGoogleExtensions-20200424"

        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev14"
    }
}
```

does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

the full stack trace is

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
File being compiled: /Users/Streetwizard/Documents/Formiik/formiik-android/FormiikFXL/login/src/main/java/com/kata/formiik/login/LoginActivity.kt
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmBackendFacade.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFiles(JvmBackendFacade.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:635)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:194)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:346)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:240)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while generating code for:
FUN name:onCreate visibility:protected modality:OPEN <> ($this:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity, savedInstanceState:android.os.Bundle?) returnType:kotlin.Unit
  overridden:
    protected/*protected and package*/ open fun onCreate (p0: android.os.Bundle?): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
  $this: VALUE_PARAMETER name:<this> type:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity
  VALUE_PARAMETER name:savedInstanceState index:0 type:android.os.Bundle?
  BLOCK_BODY
    CALL 'protected/*protected and package*/ open fun onCreate (p0: android.os.Bundle?): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity' superQualifier='CLASS IR_EXTERNAL_JAVA_DECLARATION_STUB CLASS name:AppCompatActivity modality:OPEN visibility:public superTypes:[androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity; androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatCallback; androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder.SupportParentable; androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.DelegateProvider]' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
      $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
      p0: GET_VAR 'savedInstanceState: android.os.Bundle? declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=android.os.Bundle? origin=null
    WHEN type=kotlin.Unit origin=IF
      BRANCH
        if: CALL 'public final fun not (): kotlin.Boolean [operator] declared in kotlin.Boolean' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=EXCL
          $this: CALL 'public open fun isTaskRoot (): kotlin.Boolean [fake_override] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=GET_PROPERTY
            $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
        then: BLOCK type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
          VAR name:intentAction type:kotlin.String? [val]
            CALL 'public open fun getAction (): kotlin.String? declared in android.content.Intent' type=kotlin.String? origin=GET_PROPERTY
              $this: CALL 'public open fun getIntent (): android.content.Intent? [fake_override] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=android.content.Intent? origin=GET_PROPERTY
                $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
          WHEN type=kotlin.Unit origin=IF
            BRANCH
              if: CALL 'public final fun ANDAND (arg0: kotlin.Boolean, arg1: kotlin.Boolean): kotlin.Boolean declared in kotlin.internal.ir' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
                arg0: CALL 'public final fun ANDAND (arg0: kotlin.Boolean, arg1: kotlin.Boolean): kotlin.Boolean declared in kotlin.internal.ir' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
                  arg0: CALL 'public open fun hasCategory (p0: kotlin.String?): kotlin.Boolean declared in android.content.Intent' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
                    $this: CALL 'public open fun getIntent (): android.content.Intent? [fake_override] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=android.content.Intent? origin=GET_PROPERTY
                      $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
                    p0: CONST String type=kotlin.String value="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                  arg1: CALL 'public final fun not (): kotlin.Boolean [operator] declared in kotlin.Boolean' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=EXCLEQ
                    $this: CALL 'public final fun EQEQ (arg0: kotlin.Any?, arg1: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Boolean declared in kotlin.internal.ir' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=EXCLEQ
                      arg0: GET_VAR 'val intentAction: kotlin.String? [val] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=kotlin.String? origin=null
                      arg1: CONST Null type=kotlin.Nothing? value=null
                arg1: CALL 'public final fun EQEQ (arg0: kotlin.Any?, arg1: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Boolean declared in kotlin.internal.ir' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=EQEQ
                  arg0: GET_VAR 'val intentAction: kotlin.String? [val] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=kotlin.String? origin=null
                  arg1: CONST String type=kotlin.String value="android.intent.action.MAIN"
              then: BLOCK type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
                CALL 'public open fun finish (): kotlin.Unit [fake_override] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
                  $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
                RETURN type=kotlin.Nothing from='protected open fun onCreate (savedInstanceState: android.os.Bundle?): kotlin.Unit declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity'
                  GET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_OBJECT_INSTANCE name:INSTANCE type:kotlin.Unit visibility:public [final,static]' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
    CALL 'public open fun setContentView (p0: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit [fake_override] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
      $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
      p0: GET_FIELD 'FIELD IR_EXTERNAL_JAVA_DECLARATION_STUB name:login_activity_login type:kotlin.Int visibility:public [static]' type=kotlin.Int origin=GET_PROPERTY
    CALL 'private final fun initializeObservers (): kotlin.Unit declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
      $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
    CALL 'public open fun addTextChangedListener (p0: android.text.TextWatcher?): kotlin.Unit [fake_override] declared in com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
      $this: CALL 'public final fun <get-activityLoginUserTextInputEditText> (): com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? declared in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.login_activity_login' type=com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? origin=GET_PROPERTY
        $receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
      p0: GET_FIELD 'FIELD PROPERTY_BACKING_FIELD name:textWatcher type:android.text.TextWatcher visibility:private [final]' type=android.text.TextWatcher origin=GET_PROPERTY
        receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
    COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
      CALL 'public final fun addTextChangedListener$default (beforeTextChanged: kotlin.Function4<@[ParameterName(name = 'text')] kotlin.CharSequence?, @[ParameterName(name = 'start')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'count')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'after')] kotlin.Int, kotlin.Unit>?, onTextChanged: kotlin.Function4<@[ParameterName(name = 'text')] kotlin.CharSequence?, @[ParameterName(name = 'start')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'before')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'count')] kotlin.Int, kotlin.Unit>?, afterTextChanged: kotlin.Function1<@[ParameterName(name = 'text')] android.text.Editable?, kotlin.Unit>?, $mask0: kotlin.Int, $handler: kotlin.Any?): android.text.TextWatcher [inline] declared in androidx.core.widget.TextViewKt' type=android.text.TextWatcher origin=null
        $receiver: BLOCK type=com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText origin=null
          VAR IR_TEMPORARY_VARIABLE name:tmp0 type:com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? [val]
            CALL 'public final fun <get-activityLoginPasswordTextInputEditText> (): com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? declared in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.login_activity_login' type=com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? origin=GET_PROPERTY
              $receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
          COMPOSITE type=com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText origin=null
            CALL 'public final fun checkExpressionValueIsNotNull (value: kotlin.Any?, expression: kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit declared in kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
              value: GET_VAR 'val tmp0: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? [val] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? origin=null
              expression: CONST String type=kotlin.String value="this.activityLoginPasswordTextInputEditText"
            GET_VAR 'val tmp0: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? [val] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? origin=null
        beforeTextChanged: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Function4<@[ParameterName(name = 'text')] kotlin.CharSequence?, @[ParameterName(name = 'start')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'count')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'after')] kotlin.Int, kotlin.Unit>? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
          CONST Null type=kotlin.Function4<@[ParameterName(name = 'text')] kotlin.CharSequence?, @[ParameterName(name = 'start')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'count')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'after')] kotlin.Int, kotlin.Unit>? value=null
        onTextChanged: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Function4<@[ParameterName(name = 'text')] kotlin.CharSequence?, @[ParameterName(name = 'start')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'before')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'count')] kotlin.Int, kotlin.Unit>? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
          CONST Null type=kotlin.Function4<@[ParameterName(name = 'text')] kotlin.CharSequence?, @[ParameterName(name = 'start')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'before')] kotlin.Int, @[ParameterName(name = 'count')] kotlin.Int, kotlin.Unit>? value=null
        afterTextChanged: BLOCK type=kotlin.Function1<android.text.Editable?, kotlin.Unit> origin=LAMBDA
          COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
          FUNCTION_REFERENCE 'private final fun onCreate$lambda-0 ($this: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity, it: android.text.Editable?): kotlin.Unit declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=kotlin.Function1<android.text.Editable?, kotlin.Unit> origin=LAMBDA
            $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
        $mask0: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=3
        $handler: CONST Null type=kotlin.Any? value=null
      COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
    CALL 'public open fun setOnClickListener (p0: android.view.View.OnClickListener?): kotlin.Unit [fake_override] declared in com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
      $this: CALL 'public final fun <get-activityLoginOAuthenticationLoginTextView> (): com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView? declared in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.login_activity_login' type=com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView? origin=GET_PROPERTY
        $receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
      p0: BLOCK type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided> origin=null
        CLASS LAMBDA_IMPL CLASS name:<no name provided> modality:FINAL visibility:public/*package*/ superTypes:[android.view.View.OnClickListener?]
          $this: VALUE_PARAMETER INSTANCE_RECEIVER name:<this> type:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided>
          FIELD FAKE_OVERRIDE name:receiver type:kotlin.Any? visibility:protected [fake_override]
          CONSTRUCTOR GENERATED_MEMBER_IN_CALLABLE_REFERENCE visibility:public/*package*/ <> ($this:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity) returnType:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided> [primary]
            VALUE_PARAMETER BOUND_RECEIVER_PARAMETER name:$this index:0 type:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity
            BLOCK_BODY
              SET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_CAPTURED_VALUE name:$this type:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity visibility:private [final]' type=kotlin.Unit origin=INITIALIZER_OF_FIELD_FOR_CAPTURED_VALUE
                receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided> declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided>' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided> origin=null
                value: GET_VAR '$this: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided>.<init>' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
              DELEGATING_CONSTRUCTOR_CALL 'public constructor <init> () [primary] declared in kotlin.Any'
              BLOCK type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
          FUN name:onClick visibility:public modality:FINAL <> ($this:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided>, it:android.view.View?) returnType:kotlin.Unit
            overridden:
              public abstract fun onClick (p0: android.view.View?): kotlin.Unit declared in android.view.View.OnClickListener
            $this: VALUE_PARAMETER INSTANCE_RECEIVER name:<this> type:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided>
            VALUE_PARAMETER name:it index:0 type:android.view.View?
            BLOCK_BODY
              CALL 'public final fun launchOAuthentication (): kotlin.Unit declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginViewModel' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
                $this: CALL 'public final fun access$getViewModel ($this: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity): com.kata.formiik.login.LoginViewModel declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginViewModel origin=GET_PROPERTY
                  $this: GET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_CAPTURED_VALUE name:$this type:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity visibility:private [final]' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
                    receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided> declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided>.onClick' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided> origin=null
          FIELD FIELD_FOR_CAPTURED_VALUE name:$this type:com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity visibility:private [final]
        CONSTRUCTOR_CALL 'public/*package*/ constructor <init> ($this: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity) [primary] declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided>' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate.<no name provided> origin=null
          $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
    CALL 'public final fun setText (p0: kotlin.CharSequence?): kotlin.Unit [fake_override] declared in com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
      $this: CALL 'public final fun <get-activityLoginPasswordTextInputEditText> (): com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? declared in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.login_activity_login' type=com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText? origin=GET_PROPERTY
        $receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
      p0: CALL 'public final fun <get-previouslyLoggedPassword> (): kotlin.String declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginViewModel' type=kotlin.String origin=GET_PROPERTY
        $this: CALL 'private final fun <get-viewModel> (): com.kata.formiik.login.LoginViewModel declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginViewModel origin=GET_PROPERTY
          $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
    CALL 'public final fun setText (p0: kotlin.CharSequence?): kotlin.Unit [fake_override] declared in com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView' type=kotlin.Unit origin=EQ
      $this: CALL 'public final fun <get-activityLoginVersionTextView> (): com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView? declared in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.login_activity_login' type=com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView? origin=GET_PROPERTY
        $receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
      p0: CALL 'public final fun <get-informationVersion> (): kotlin.String declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginViewModel' type=kotlin.String origin=GET_PROPERTY
        $this: CALL 'private final fun <get-viewModel> (): com.kata.formiik.login.LoginViewModel declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginViewModel origin=GET_PROPERTY
          $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
    CALL 'private final fun requestMissingPermissions (): kotlin.Unit declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
      $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null
    CALL 'private final fun setupTestEnvironmentButton (): kotlin.Unit declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
      $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity declared in com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity.onCreate' type=com.kata.formiik.login.LoginActivity origin=null

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generateMethod(ClassCodegen.kt:342)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generateDeclaration(ClassCodegen.kt:302)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generate(ClassCodegen.kt:148)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen$Companion.generate(ClassCodegen.kt:290)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmBackendFacade.kt:95)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unhandled intrinsic in ExpressionCodegen: FUN IR_EXTERNAL_DECLARATION_STUB name:<get-activityLoginUserTextInputEditText> visibility:public modality:FINAL <> ($receiver:android.app.Activity) returnType:com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText?
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitFunctionAccess(ExpressionCodegen.kt:373)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.kt:171)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrCallGenerator$DefaultImpls.genValueAndPut(IrCallGenerator.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrCallGenerator$DefaultCallGenerator.genValueAndPut(IrCallGenerator.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitFunctionAccess(ExpressionCodegen.kt:411)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitStatementContainer(ExpressionCodegen.kt:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockBody(ExpressionCodegen.kt:359)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockBody(ExpressionCodegen.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockBodyImpl.accept(IrBlockBodyImpl.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generate(ExpressionCodegen.kt:200)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.doGenerate(FunctionCodegen.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:51)
    ... 41 more


e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation

Execution failed for task ':login:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

**UPDATE March 24 2021**

Sorry everyone for the delay,

I never managed to compile a multi-module project with any of the compose developer preview versions, I asked a lot in the official compose slack channel and nothing worked; after compose became alpha my team and I updated the project to the 1st alpha version and Canary version of android studio at that time (which i really don't remember), and then everything worked as expected :D

Right now we are using the Android Studio Canary 8 and the compose beta 02, everything is working superfine, we even took the decision to launch some modules all made with compose in production and we haven't received any crashes in crashlytics in about 1 moth in production.

We also are still using the now deprecated kotlin synthetics in some parts of the app, the android gradle plugin shows some warnings about the deprecation but its still working as expected, and soon everything in the app will be made using compose

Comment: I am also facing same problem, If you find out solution, please let me know

Comment: did you ever solve this because im getting the same thing when using compose on an existing project

Answer (score 1):

There was the same problem but it was caused not by modules, but by problems with android studio, it worked for me on android studio 4.1 canary 10 and with the same build parameters

[enter link description here](https://github.com/bigmeco/TestArchitectures/blob/master/build.gradle)

[enter link description here](https://github.com/bigmeco/TestArchitectures/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Kotlin Synthetics, try changing to defined view binding. I got a similar error while integrating Twilio, and that fixed it right up. Good luck!